# Including Bootstrap messes CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I made a simple burger button using html and css, everything worked fine but I need to include bootstrap for alignements and all in my project and that's messing my css somehow.

**without including bootstrap**

[image]

**After including bootstrap**

[image]

I tried including bootstrap before my css stylesheet so that it doesn't overwride it but it didn't work.

here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<button class="menuButton">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <span></span>
        <span id="midspan"></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.menuButton{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 0vmin;   
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    animation: buttonAnim 0.75s  forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    float: right;

}

@keyframes buttonAnim {
    100%{
        width:3vmin;
        right: 0;
    }
}

.menuButton span{
    width: 3vmin;
    height: 0.2vmin;
    margin-bottom: 0.5vmin;
    margin-top: 0.5vmin;
    display: block;
    background-color: coral;

}

.buttonContainer{
    width: 3vmin;
}

#midspan {
    transform: translate(1vmin, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.menuButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menuButton:hover #midspan{
    transform: translate(0);
}
```

Comment: Open your file in any browser that has decent developer tools (Firefox or Chomium-based browsers, sometimes called F12 developer tools), right click the element and inspect it. You should see which rules are affecting it (usually on the right) and what file contains said rules (e.g. your CSS or Bootstrap). That said, if you're only including bootstrap for one single thing, why not go without it and DIY? Bootstrap isn't really made for cherry-picking features and it affects a ton of other elements, causing conflicts like yours.

Comment: inspect the element (before/after) and then change the added css, and make sure your element is not wrapped in a bootstrap class such as `container`

Comment: Reading the Bootstrap source file, you'll find rules for root elements like hr, h1-6, p, ul, ol, li and so on. Introducing it to an existing site is bound to cause headaches. It's the Bootstrap way or no way. [Have a read for yourself.](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the default `bootstrap.css` file overrides default styles on various HTML elements.

If you just want to have a responsive grid layout with no styles you can include [Bootstrap's CSS grid layout file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#css-files) `bootstrap-grid.css` or `bootstrap-grid.min.css` in your HTML, and that should do the trick:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
```

You can find these inside their "compiled package" available to download [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/#compiled-css-and-js).

**Note**: This zip file contains a lot of files, just use `bootstrap-grid.css` or `bootstrap-grid.min.css`.